# Equation of a plane equidistant from two points $A$ and $B$?

Tags: vector-spaces

Suppose I have two points $A=(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $B=(x_2,y_2,z_2)$. Suppose I want to find the equation of the plane equidistant from these points of form $ax+by+cz+d=0$. What is the equation in terms of the coordinates of $A$ and $B$

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you mean that all points in the plane are equidistant from $A$ and $B$, then notice that the vector $$v:= v_2-v_1= ( x_2-x_1,y_2-y_1,z_2-z_1 )^T$$ is normal to the desired plane. Furthermore, the midpoint of the line segment between $A$ and $B$ must lie in this plane. The midpoint is the point $m=\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2},\frac{y_1+y_2}{2},\frac{z_1+z_2}{2}\right)$. Can you come up with the equation for a plane if you have a normal vector and a point that lies in the plane?

Answer (score 4):

If the point $P = (x,y, z)$ is on the bisector plane, then we know $distance(P,A) = distance(P,B)$. Therefore
$$ (x-x_1)^2 + (y-y_1)^2 + (z-z_1)^2 = (x-x_2)^2 + (y-y_2)^2 + (z-z_2)^2$$

If you multiply everything out, you'll find that all the squared terms disappear, and you'll be left with an equation that can be massaged into the form $ax+by+cz+d =0$.

Alternatively, there is a geometric approach: we know that the plane passes through the point that's half way between $A$ and $B$. This is the point $(A+B)/2$.

Also we know that the normal vector of the plane is the vector between $A$ and $B$, which is $B-A$.

Then, maybe you know how to get the equation of a plane if you have its normal vector and a point that lies on it ?

Answer (score 3):

For calculating a plane you need a point and a normal vector.

A point $P$ of your plane is fore sure the center point of $A$ and $B$. (because of the same distances to $A$ and $B$.
$$P = \frac{A+B}{2}$$

A normal vector $\overrightarrow{n}$ onto the plane is just the vector $\overrightarrow{AB}$.
$$\overrightarrow{n}=\overrightarrow{AB} = B - A$$

Then you can creat your plane with:
$$\overrightarrow{n}X=\overrightarrow{n}P$$

Comment: $P$ is a point, and $n$ is a vector. What is the product of a point and a vector?/

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is necessary to define what it is here meant with

> plane equidistant from these points

Henceforth, in the following it will be assumed that for such a plane: each point of it is equidistant from the two given points.

The answer to your question is stated in the following proposition.

> **Proposition**. Let $\big(\mathbb R ^n, \|\cdot\|_2\big)$ be the usual $n$-dimensional Euclidean space and let two points be represented by the two vectors $p,q\in \mathbb R ^n$. The Hyperplane $H\subseteq \mathbb R ^n$ (seen as $n-1$ dimensional vector affine subspace of $\mathbb R ^n$) that is equidistant from $p$ and $q$ is given by the equation:
> $$(p-q)\cdot x = \frac{1}{2} \big(\|p\|_2^2- \|q\|_2^2\big)$$

*Proof*. A hyperplane is uniquely described by the equation $u\cdot x= c$, for $c\in \mathbb R$ and $u\in \mathbb R ^n$ such that $\|u\|_2=1$.

- (Finding $u$) Typically, $u$ is the unit vector orthogonal to the plane: in this case, an such an orthogonal element is given by $p-q$, dividing it then by its norm gives $\frac{p-q}{\|p-q\|_2}=:u$.
- (Finding $c$) Along the path between $p$ and $q$, given this choice of metric, the point equidistant form $p$ and $q$ is $\frac{p+q}{2}$. This is simple to check as, for instance, by considering the linear path from $q$ to $p$ given by $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R^n, t\mapsto q+t (p-q)$, the midpoint at $t=\frac{1}{2}$ is equidistant form $p$ and $q$ and hence finds itself in $H$. So, one can use this to obtain the remaining missing information about $c$: by inserting this this point in the above equation and solving for $c$ one gets
  $$\frac{p-q}{\|p-q\|_2}\cdot \frac{p+q}{2} = \frac{1}{2\|p-q\|_2} \big(p\cdot p -q\cdot p + p\cdot q - q\cdot q\big) = \frac{1}{2\|p-q\|_2} \big(\|p\|_2^2- \|q\|_2^2\big) =: c$$
  This is due to the linearity and symmetry of the real scalar product.

At this point the equation $u\cdot x=c$ is completely determined and possibly one could limit himself to this. It is to remark, though, that "de-norming" the result for $u$ and $c$ gives a more concise formulation, hence $\tilde{u} := u\|p-q\|_2$ and $\tilde{c} := c\|p-q\|_2$ give the final result in the proposition. $\square$